# Change node color in D3 sankey diagram

Tags: d3.js, sankey-diagram, observablehq

How could I change the node color in [this sankey diagram](https://observablehq.com/@brunurb/flow-o-matic-sankey-silvia)

I wanted the two bottom central nodes to be the same color as the previous link color (in this case the bottom node red and the one above it orange)
Noob here, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want just those two specific nodes getting their colour from the source links, but none of the others (by looking at the rest of the logic and assuming that that code is yours). If that's correct, the *ad hoc* solution is just...

```
if (d.depth === 1 && (d.name === "2 ou + retenções" || d.name === "1 retenção")) return d.targetLinks[0].color;
```

..., right at the beginning of the callback.

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo Furtado, It worked but I also wanted the colors to be brighter, I tried .brighter(0.5) but it did not work  [Link to diagram] (https://observablehq.com/@brunurb/flow-o-matic-sankey-silvia)

Comment: `return d3.color(d.targetLinks[0].color).brighter(0.5)`